# How to align RadioButtonGroupInput of react-admin horizontally?

Tags: layout, alignment, react-admin

While using react-admin's RadioButtonGroupInput,

RadioButtonGroupInput's each Radio Buttons are always aligned vertically.

I want to align it horizontally.

I was trying to many way except implementing custom component. but nothing works.

```
<RadioButtonGroupInput source="category" choices={[
    { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: 'photography', name: 'Photography' },
]} />
```

It is aligned vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Use this properties

**options={{'row':true}}**

```
<RadioButtonGroupInput source="category" choices={[
    { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: 'photography', name: 'Photography' },
    options={{'row':true}}
]} />
```

Then RadioButtonGroupInput pass the option to RadioGroup
then it is aligned horizontally.